# Microsoft.Powershell.SDK Causes .Net Core Application to exit when packaged in MSIX

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, msix

Using Visual Studio 2019 I am creating a Windows Application Packaging Project and adding a .Net Core 3.0 Console application to it.  All is good so far.

Then I add package microsoft.powershell.sdk through NuGet to .Net Console project.

It runs fine when launched directly. But when launched through MSIX packaging project the console windows disappears immediately.  I see no errors.

My .Net console application has no custom code in it.  It's just the default 'Hello World'.  I can even package the project and sideload it onto my computer.  The sideloaded application behaves in the same way - .Net core console application exits as soon as it stops.